# How to modify a file on a remote machine using perl

Tags: perl

I have one file on a remote linux machine. I want to do some modification in that file from my host machine where I am executing the script.

I am using Perl here

Now how to connect to other machine using perl. And how to deal with file modification.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you add more details on what connectivity is available, question is somewhat vague to answer precisely, but since SSH/SCP/SFTP is available mostly everywhere this day, you'll probably want one of the many Perl's modules dealing with those from [CPAN](http://cpan.org). You might want to try [`Net::uFTP`](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3auFTP) because it provides universal interface to many other modules.

You can also just call `scp` with `system`, perform modifications locally and transfer file back.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the file in place on the remote machine using [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign).

Another possibility is to mount the remote file system locally with `sshfs`, and change the file as it were local. The downside of this is that if your script ends prematurely because of some error the remote file systems may remount mounted.